# developing for nokia s40 sdk

Tags: sdk, nokia, nokia-s40

Is it possible to connect a keyboard to a mobile phone (via its USB port) and receive input from it (just as if you would type in a text editor)? I am trying to do this programmatically.
I've installed NetBeans along with Nokia S40 5th Edition SDK. I have searched all over the internet but i haven't got anything.

Can someone give me some ideas on how to realize this app?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no ways 3rd party developers could add USB keyboards to the Nokia S40 devices. If you really want to use older Nokia devices for the task, I would suggest checking Symbian 3 devices that have USB-OTG support, they might indeed support the approach better.

Comment: Well that`s disappointing.. i might try it with an android phone or if i do find a Symbian phone i`ll give it a try with it too. Thanks for your reply.